# XSLT Muenchian Grouped Table -- Limit number of cells per row

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML is here, it's actually about 300 movie elements long, but this is just to give you a sense --

```
<mediaList>        
<movie id="1325947" dateCreated="2014-04-23">
        <title>Gator</title>
        <director>Burt Reynolds</director>
        <genre>Action</genre>
        <writer>William W. Norton</writer>
        <language>English</language>
        <year>1976</year>
        <callNumber href="http://endeavor.flo.org/vwebv/holdingsInfo?bibId=1325947">[DVD] PN1995.9 .A3 R49 2003</callNumber>
        <coverArt href="Pics/Gator.jpg"/>
    </movie>

    <movie id="1094761" dateCreated="2014-04-23">
        <title>Assault on Precinct 13</title>
        <director>Jean-François Richet</director>
        <genre>Action</genre>
        <genre>Police</genre>
        <writer>James DeMonaco</writer>
        <language>English</language>
        <year>2005</year>
        <callNumber href="http://endeavor.flo.org/vwebv/holdingsInfo?bibId=1094761">[DVD] PN1995.9 .A3 R53 2005</callNumber>
        <coverArt href="Pics/AssaultonPrecinct13.jpg"/>
    </movie>

    <movie id="716486" dateCreated="2014-04-23">
        <title>Thunder Road</title>
        <director>Arthur Ripley</director>
        <genre>Action</genre>
        <genre>Crime</genre>
        <writer>James Atlee Phillips</writer>
        <writer>Walter Wise</writer>
        <language>English</language>
        <year>1958</year>
        <callNumber href="http://endeavor.flo.org/vwebv/holdingsInfo?bibId=716486">[DVD] PN1995.9 .A3 R57 2000</callNumber>
        <coverArt href="Pics/ThunderRoad.jpg"/>
    </movie>

    <movie id="1335109" dateCreated="2014-04-23">
        <title>From Dusk Till Dawn</title>
        <director>Robert Rodriguez</director>
        <genre>Action</genre>
        <genre>Vampire</genre>
        <writer>Quentin Tarantino</writer>
        <screenplay href="http://endeavor.flo.org/vwebv/holdingsInfo?bibId=527135">PN1997 .F7466 T37 1995</screenplay>
        <language>English</language>
        <year>1998</year>
        <callNumber href="http://endeavor.flo.org/vwebv/holdingsInfo?bibId=1335109">[DVD] PN1995.9 .A3 R63 1998</callNumber>
        <coverArt href="Pics/FromDuskTillDawn.jpg"/>
    </movie>
</mediaList>
```

I have a several different style sheets I'm using on it, and one of them is intended to transform them into a nice pretty layout of pictures and titles. That style sheet is here:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="genre" match="genre" use="."/>

    <xsl:param name="groupBy" select="'genre'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">

        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mediaList.css"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates
                    select="movie//*[local-name() = $groupBy][generate-id() = generate-id(key($groupBy, .)[1])]" mode="toc">
                <xsl:sort order="ascending"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:apply-templates
                    select="movie//*[local-name() = $groupBy][generate-id() = generate-id(key($groupBy, .)[1])]" mode="contents">
                    <xsl:sort order="ascending"/>
                    <xsl:sort select="title"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="movie//*" mode="contents">
        <h1>
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </a>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </h1>
        <table class="genre">
            <tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key($groupBy, .)/ancestor::movie">
                    <xsl:sort select="title"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="movie">

        <td class="genre">
            <div class="image">
                <div class="trick"/>
                <img>
                    <xsl:attribute name="src">
                        <xsl:value-of select="coverArt/@href"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="alt">Movie poster for '<xsl:value-of select="title"/>'
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </img>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="callNumber/@href"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            </a>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="movie//*" mode="toc">
        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">#<xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </a>
        <br/>
    </xsl:template>
</stylesheet>
```

The problem I'm having is that currently each genre is given ONE row in its table, and it requires tons of scrolling to see all the movies -- I want a way to force a limit say, 7 or 10  per 
So each genre is all contained within a single table, but it's a fixed number of cells per row

Any thoughts?  XSLT 1.0 OR 2.0 solutions would be much obliged

Answer (score 0):

You could use `subsequence()` to return the desired number of movies (`td` elements).

Try changing this template:

```
<xsl:template match="movie//*" mode="contents">
    <h1>
        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </a>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </h1>
    <table class="genre">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key($groupBy, .)/ancestor::movie">
                <xsl:sort select="title"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

To this template:

```
<xsl:template match="movie//*" mode="contents">
    <h1>
        <!--Used attribute value template to cleanup code.-->
        <a id="{.}"/>            
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </h1>
    <table class="genre">
        <tr>
            <!--Wrapped xsl:apply-templates in xsl:variable.-->
            <xsl:variable name="movies">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key($groupBy, .)/ancestor::movie">
                    <xsl:sort select="title"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>                    
            </xsl:variable>
            <!--Output the 1st through 10th td's stored in $movies.-->
            <xsl:copy-of select="subsequence($movies/td,1,10)"/>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about attribute value templates! I'd never come across those before. While your addition helps, in that it limits the <tr> to 10 <td>, i'm looking to still contain ALL the movies I have, so I need to then start a NEW <tr> with another 10 action movies